# How to run unit tests when running the application in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We're trying to run automated tests of our functions using a unit test program in visual studio but we need to connect to the database in order to run them successfully. The program only connects to the database when the whole solution is run, so is there a way to run the unit tests when you run the solution?

Comment: can you post your unit test code? It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: You want to run integration tests not unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

The main point of unit testing is separating everything else from the class under test. For example, when you testing your `UserService` to see if `CreateNewUser()` function is successful or not, you need to remove all dependencies by using **test doubles as mock, stub, fake etc.**

After creating a double for the dependencies(database connection), you can call your function to see it is working **if every dependency works correctly**. So you will see if your **unit** of code is doing its job.

Comment: We know we're not doing a unit test anymore but we can't create mocks because the automated testing we're expected to put out has to test the actual functions. I just wanted to know if it was possible to use a unit test project in visual studio that would access the appconfig where the connection string is stored.